# Unable to connect to android BLE after android update

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been working on a project in which I need to connect to a BLE and communicate with Arduino through BLE. Every thing worked fine until I update my device to Android M. I haven't changed anything in my project but now my app not connecting to BLE.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem. All you need to do is to enable *ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION* & *ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION* 
permission in your manifest and also you need to enable location service(by turning on GPS).

Answer (score 0):

Android M needed GPS should be on for effective working of bluetooth, that's why it is unable to connect to android BLE. Give GPS permissions also. Hope it will help

Comment: This is not true. You don't need gps permissions to use BLE.